# Joining 3 tables on MySQL + 2 where commands

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry if my title isn't as technical as it should be, just new to the MySQL stuff.

I have 3 tables.

- PC01_CONSULTATIONS,
- PC02_CONSULTATION_TYPES,
- PC12_STATUS_CODES.

I gave each table a short name so PC01_CONSULTATIONS - PC01, PC02_CONSULTATION_TYPES - PC02, PC12_STATUS_CODES - PC12.

I joined `PC01 + PC02` using the similar column in each table which was `"PC01_CONSULTATIONS.PC02_CONS_TYPE_ID"` and `"PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID"` where `PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID = 1`
this was the code I used

```
select * from PC01_CONSULTATIONS PC01

join PC02_CONSULTATION_TYPES PC02

on PC01.pc02_cons_type_id = PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID

where PC02.cons_type_id = 1
```

- which worked fine initially, but now in addition to all this I need to join the third table `"PC12_STATUS_CODES"`. The similar column between PC01 and PC12 is the `"PC01_ONSULTATIONS.PC12_STATUS_CODE_ID" + "PC12_STATUS_CODES.STATUS_CODE_ID"`.
- if this is joined into the already existing code i have i also need to add in another 'where' command. The reason PC12 table is being joined to the code is so that i can retrieve the records where PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID = 2. So ontop of the current "where PC02.cons_type_id = 1" i would have to add in "AND PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID = 2" right?
- The code i made (which obviously doesn't work) is the following, any tips on how to correctly create this code i can retrieve the right records would be well appreciated. Thank you.

  ```
   select * from PC01_CONSULTATIONS PC01
   join PC02_CONSULTATION_TYPES PC02 
   join PC12_STATUS_CODES PC12
   on PC01.PC02_CONS_TYPE_ID = PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID
   on PC01.PC12_STATUS_CODE_ID = PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID
   where PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID = 1 and PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID = 2
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from PC01_CONSULTATIONS PC01    
    join PC02_CONSULTATION_TYPES PC02 on PC01.PC02_CONS_TYPE_ID = PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID
    join PC12_STATUS_CODES PC12 on PC01.PC12_STATUS_CODE_ID = PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID
    where PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID = 1 and PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks dude, yeah it works!

would you be able to talk me through what you did quickly? like what i did wrong and how you correctled it? I really appreciate it!

Comment: For performing a `join (inner join)` operation between two tables, you need to pass the columns on which the `join` should be performed. In your case, for the first `join`, there were no columns passed. So it was not able to join the columns in the two tables. Your logic was right, but the position of the statements was wrong.

Comment: I see, yeah it makes much more sense how you have done it. Thank you for that.

Comment: You are welocome ... :)  You can mark the answer as accepted, so that I can gain some reputation ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are writing the request false:

here is the right one

```
select * from PC01_CONSULTATIONS PC01    
join PC02_CONSULTATION_TYPES PC02    
on PC01.PC02_CONS_TYPE_ID = PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID
join PC12_STATUS_CODES PC12    
on PC01.PC12_STATUS_CODE_ID = PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID    
where PC02.CONS_TYPE_ID = 1 and PC12.STATUS_CODE_ID = 2
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the answer, i understand where i was going wrong now.